# Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java

Tags: java, collections

What is the easiest way to convert a `List` to a `Set` in Java?

Answer (score 1244, accepted):

```
Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>(myList);
```

Comment: While correct this answer lacks sufficient technical context to warrant being the best/accepted answer, because there are pitfalls here depending on which implementations of `Set` and `Map` one is using; `HashSet` is _assumed_ here.

Comment: @Madbreaks Came here specifically for that problem and would recommend using Ramesh's solution with Abdul's explanation to anyone else that is interested in trying to do this

Comment: Better than Baeldung

Answer (score 164):

I agree with sepp2k, but there are some other details that might matter:

```
new HashSet<Foo>(myList);
```

will give you an unsorted set which doesn't have duplicates. In this case, duplication is identified using the .equals() method on your objects. This is done in combination with the .hashCode() method. (For more on equality look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java))

An alternative that gives a sorted set is:

```
new TreeSet<Foo>(myList);
```

This works if Foo implements Comparable. If it doesn't then you may want to use a comparator:

```
Set<Foo> lSet = new TreeSet<Foo>(someComparator);
lSet.addAll(myList);
```

This depends on either compareTo() (from the comparable interface) or compare() (from the comparator) to ensure uniqueness. So, if you just care about uniqueness, use the HashSet. If you're after sorting, then consider the TreeSet. (Remember: Optimize later!) If time efficiency matters use a HashSet if space efficiency matters, look at TreeSet. Note that more efficient implementations of Set and Map are available through Trove (and other locations).

Comment: Thanks for included the custom Comparator use case!

Answer (score 75):

If you use the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library:

```
Set<Foo> set = Sets.newHashSet(list);
```

or, better:

```
Set<Foo> set = ImmutableSet.copyOf(list);
```

Comment: Why is ImmutableSet.copyOf better?

Comment: What advantages does Guava's newHashSet() have over the basic java new HashSet()?

Comment: @Nelda.techspiress The [javadoc](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet(java.lang.Iterable)) discusses when the method should or should not be used. Note the final part: *this method is not very useful and will likely be deprecated in the future.* Though I'm a bit surprised consistency is not mentioned as a factor, as it is with [`ImmutableSet.of()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/14.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html#of()), for example. EDIT: it may not be factor because *all* the overloads are unneeded.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reference @shmosel, but I was looking more for empirical knowledge. For those who have used Guava, why would Guava be chosen over HashSet?

Answer (score 75):

**Java**- **addAll**

```
set.addAll(aList);
```

**Java**- **new Object**

```
new HashSet<>(list)
```

**Java-8**

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Using Guva**

```
 Sets.newHashSet(list)
```

**Apache Commons**

```
CollectionUtils.addAll(targetSet, sourceList);
```

**Java 10**

```
var set = Set.copyOf(list);
```

Comment: Are there any performance differences among them?

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the best answer.
Thanks !

Answer (score 36):

Using java 8 you can use stream:

```
List<Integer> mylist = Arrays.asList(100, 101, 102);
Set<Integer> myset = mylist.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Have you checked the performance penalty on this? this would do an iterable+iterator, a new HashSet(), and then for each list item, an addAll() call on the new set. Overall, cca. 5 objects created for something as simple as a new HashSet(list).

Comment: @AgostonHorvath Thank you for your comment. I was originally looking for that information when I came here.

Answer (score 18):

```
Set<E> alphaSet  = new HashSet<E>(<your List>);
```

or complete example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class ListToSet
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> alphaList = new ArrayList<String>();
        alphaList.add("A");
        alphaList.add("B");
        alphaList.add("C");
        alphaList.add("A");
        alphaList.add("B");
        System.out.println("List values .....");
        for (String alpha : alphaList)
        {
            System.out.println(alpha);
        }
        Set<String> alphaSet = new HashSet<String>(alphaList);
        System.out.println("\nSet values .....");
        for (String alpha : alphaSet)
        {
            System.out.println(alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a complete code example. One additional note here is that hashing isn't guaranteed to be the same from run to run. That means that the list printed after 'Set values .....' might be 'ABC' one run and 'CBA' another run. As I mentioned in my answer, you could use a tree set to get a stable ordering. Another option would be to use a LinkedHashSet which remembers the order that items were added to it.

Answer (score 11):

Remember that, converting from List to Set will remove duplicates from collection because List supports duplicates but Set does not support duplicates in Java.

**Direct Conversion :** The most common and simple way to convert a List to a Set

```
// Creating a list of strings
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");

// Converting a list to set
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
```

**Apache Commons Collections :** You may also use the Commons Collections API to convert a List to a Set :-

```
// Creating a list of strings
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");

// Creating a set with the same number of members in the list 
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(4);

// Adds all of the elements in the list to the target set
CollectionUtils.addAll(set, list);
```

**Using Stream :** Another way is to convert given list to stream, then stream to set :-

```
// Creating a list of strings 
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four"); 

// Converting to set using stream 
Set<String> set = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 8):

With Java 10, you could now use [`Set#copyOf`](https://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) to easily convert a `List<E>` to an unmodifiable `Set<E>`:

Example:

```
var set = Set.copyOf(list);
```

Keep in mind that this is an unordered operation, and `null` elements are **not** permitted, as it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

If you wish for it to be modifiable, then simply pass it into the constructor a `Set` implementation.

Answer (score 7):

I would perform a Null check before converting to set.

```
if(myList != null){
Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>(myList);
}
```

Comment: Or `Set<Foo> foo = myList == null ? Collections.emptySet() : new HashSet<Foo>(myList);`

Answer (score 6):

For Java 8 it's very easy:

```
List < UserEntity > vList= new ArrayList<>(); 
vList= service(...);
Set<UserEntity> vSet= vList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: "Real" Java 8 would be to use `new ArrayList<>()` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can convert `List<>` to `Set<>`

```
Set<T> set=new HashSet<T>();

//Added dependency -> If list is null then it will throw NullPointerExcetion.

Set<T> set;
if(list != null){
    set = new HashSet<T>(list);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant casting it from List to Set.

Answer (score 5):

Let's not forget our relatively new friend, [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) stream API.
If you need to preprocess list before converting it to a set, it's better to have something like:

```
list.stream().<here goes some preprocessing>.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to use constructor

```
Set s= new HashSet(list);
```

In java 8 you can also use stream api::

```
Set s= list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to get a `Set` as:

```
    List<Integer> sourceList = new ArrayList();
    sourceList.add(1);
    sourceList.add(2);
    sourceList.add(3);
    sourceList.add(4);

    // Using Core Java
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(sourceList);  //needs null-check if sourceList can be null.

    // Java 8
    Set<Integer> set2 = sourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Integer> set3 = sourceList.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    //Guava
    Set<Integer> set4 = Sets.newHashSet(sourceList);

    // Apache commons
    Set<Integer> set5 = new HashSet<>(4);
    CollectionUtils.addAll(set5, sourceList);
```

When we use `Collectors.toSet()` it returns a set and as per the doc:`There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned`. If we want to get a `HashSet` then we can use the other alternative to get a set (check `set3`).

Answer (score 3):

A more Java 8 resilient solution with `Optional.ofNullable`

```
Set<Foo> mySet = Optional.ofNullable(myList).map(HashSet::new).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
MutableSet<Integer> mSet = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3).toSet();
MutableIntSet mIntSet = IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3).toSet();
```

The `MutableSet` interface extends `java.util.Set` whereas the `MutableIntSet` interface does not. You can also convert any `Iterable` to a `Set` using the `Sets` factory class.

```
Set<Integer> set = Sets.mutable.withAll(List.of(1, 2, 3));
```

There is more explanation of the mutable factories available in Eclipse Collections [here](https://medium.com/@donraab/as-a-matter-of-factory-part-1-mutable-75cc2c5d72d9).

If you want an `ImmutableSet` from a `List`, you can use the `Sets` factory as follows:

```
ImmutableSet<Integer> immutableSet = Sets.immutable.withAll(List.of(1, 2, 3))
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.8, the stream API can be used to convert a list to set. For example, the code below shows the conversion of a list to a set:

```java
List<String> empList = Arrays.asList("java", "python", ".net", "javaScript", "php");
Set<String> set = empList.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
set.forEach(value -> System.out.printf("%s ", value));
```

In case the list contains objects and I want to create a set out of it:

```java
List<Employee> empList = Arrays.asList(new Employee(1, 1000, "Chandra Shekhar", 6000),
new Employee(2, 1000, "Rajesh", 8000), new Employee(3, 1004, "Rahul", 9000),
new Employee(4, 1001, "Suresh", 12000), new Employee(5, 1004, "Satosh", 7000));

Set<String> set = empList.stream().map(emp -> emp.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
```