# Convert List to CopyOnWriteArraySet

Tags: java, android

Did a bunch of searching but came up blank.  I'm using GreenDao within my app and am querying my database in a specific method which results in a list.  I'd like to convert that list to a copyonwritearrayset.  Is there a simple way to do this that I'm just not seeing?

At this point the only thing I can think to do is go item by item in a for loop:

```
List<Item> list = mItemDao.queryBuilder().orderDesc(ItemDao.Properties._id)
                    .list();
            CopyOnWriteArraySet<Item> set = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<Item>();

            for (Item item : list) {
                set.add(item);
            }
return set;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set? - Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-java)

Comment: @m0ski0  it's definitely a duplicate :)  When I searched, I couldn't find anything, but when I posted, that link came up as a related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `Collection<E>#addAll(Collection<? extends E>)`

```
set.addAll(list)
```

Comment: That works.  I'm posting another answer I found as soon as I submitted the question, lol.  I'm giving you the check because this is a working answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All my searching turned up nothing, but once I posted the question, one of the related links that came up was the exact same question I had.  I'm going to go bang my head against the wall and move on.

Here's the answer to my question:

[Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-java?rq=1)