# Easiest way to convert a List to a ConcurrentSet? - Java

Tags: java

How would I convert a List, (let's say an ArrayList) to a ConcurrentSet in Java?

I'm aware of this answer: [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-java)
But I can't seem to get it to work for a ConcurrentSet.

Comment: what you mean by `ConcurrentSet`? there is one JDK implementation of thread-safe `Set` -- [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html), so you can easily use its `Collection`-arg constructor.

Comment: I've tried:
Set <String> set = new ConcurrentSet<String>(myList);
I see now that ConcurrentSet isn't part of the JDK, and is part of another library I have downloaded. I guess this is why I'm getting downvoted so harshly :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a conversion like this.

```
public static <E> Set<E> toConcurrentSet(Collection<E> coll) {
    Set<E> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    set.addAll(coll);
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Why the <E>, after the static keyword - before the return type of Set<E> ?

Comment: could be shortcutted to `Collections.newSetFromMap(list.stream().collect(toConcurrentMap(k -> k, k -> Boolean.TRUE)));`

Answer (score 0):

If with ConcurrentSet you mean a set that can be accessed concurrently, you can try:

```
Set<Foo> foo = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Foo>(myList));
```

The returned set will be thread safe.