# Check lists of objects for equality without order check in their List property

Tags: java, kotlin, assertj

Preconditions: I am deserializing a complex JSON into data class. The destination class has a bit of a complex hierarchy.

I have a list of objects List. Where ServiceFeature is the following (it's in kotlin, but does not matter):

```
data class ServiceFeature(
    val flagValue: String?,
    val effectiveFlagValue: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val attributes: List<Attribute?>?
)
```

As you can see `ServiceFeature` has an "attributes" property which includes another List of "Attribute". The main point is that Attributes in list might be in any order.
Is there a reliable way to compare two lists of `ServiceFeatures` without order check from `List<Attribute?>`

I am trying to find a solution with assertJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order does not matter for your attributes and they are unique (i.e. may not have multiple attributes of the same type) you might change the structure into a `Set<Attribute?>` instead and just use the regular compare.

If you want to preserve order but compare (unique) attributes you may convert them to set when comparing, see [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-in-java).

Comment: Thanks,
Changing List to Set in data class works like a charm
`val attributes: List<Attribute?>? ->   val attributes: Set<Attribute?>?`

Comment: What if I need to compare two lists ignoring order and the lists may contain duplicate elements? Set won't work then.

Answer (score 2):

If order of elements doesn't matter, then you can use `Set` instead of `List`. Having said that, You can use [containsExactlyInAnyOrder()](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT...)) method provided by AssertJ. This method expects var-args as an argument, so in order to convert list to array we can use [toTypedArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) along with [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) E.g.

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*

data class ServiceFeature(
        val flagValue: String?,
        val effectiveFlagValue: String?,
        val name: String?,
        val attributes: List?
)

data class Attribute(val name: String?)

class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val list1 = listOf(ServiceFeature("flagA", "effectiveFlagA", "foo", listOf(Attribute("a"), Attribute("b"))))
        val list2 = listOf(ServiceFeature("flagA", "effectiveFlagA", "foo", listOf(Attribute("b"), Attribute("a"))))
        list1.zip(list2).forEach {
            assertThat(it.first.name).isEqualTo(it.second.name)
            assertThat(it.first.effectiveFlagValue).isEqualTo(it.second.effectiveFlagValue)
            assertThat(it.first.name).isEqualTo(it.second.name)
            val toTypedArray = it.second.attributes!!.toTypedArray() // null-check as per your need
            assertThat(it.first.attributes).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(*toTypedArray)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this method. It works with Arrays, but in my case I have an Array of Objects which have one more array as property. In my case assertion fails on checking List<Attribute> for ServiceFeature

Comment: You can tweak the method to compare the lists, see updated answer