# Fetching an object of type Set<String> from a JWT?

Tags: java, collections, jjwt

I am trying to fetch some data from JSON web token, using the JJWT library : https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

The method signature is like so :

```
<T> T get(String claimName, Class<T> requiredType);
```

In a claim attribute I have a Set of type String.

When trying to fetch from this method like so

```
Claims claims - Jwts.parser()...
claims.get("Role", Set.class);
```

I get the following error

> ! io.jsonwebtoken.RequiredTypeException: Expected value to be of type:
>    interface java.util.Set, but was class java.util.ArrayList

When setting this claim the type is of Set

```
public Set<String> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}  ....


claim("Role", user.getRoles())
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON and therefore JWT does not have a concept of `Set`, retrieve the data as an Array / `ArrayList` and convert it to a Set: [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-in-java)