# Remove duplicates in an ArrayList belong a Date Field

Tags: java, list, filter, java-stream

I recieved a List of Objects from my Data Base and, I would like to remove duplicates with same id except the duplicate which have smallest date, and if the date is equal, I would like to  keep the object with the smallest "cxalap" :

For exemple :

If my list from the Data Base is the following :

```
List<NotificationCnavOP> notificationCnavOPList = [{id = 1; date = 01/01/2000; cxalap= 1}, {id=2; date = 01/01/2001; cxalap = 2}, {id=2, date = 01/01/2002; cxalap=3}, {id=2, date = 01/01/2001; cxalap=2}]
```

The new filter list will keep the first two :

```
List<NotificationCnavOP> notificationCnavOPListFiltered = [{id = 1; date = 01/01/2000; cxalap= 1}, {id=2; date = 01/01/2001; cxalap = 2}]
```

I don't have any idea of methods to use for making this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-in-java)

Comment: Is order important?

Comment: No the order is not important

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort your list first on `id`, then on the `date`, and then on `cxalap`.
2. Merge the sorted list into a `Map` with `id` as the key. In case of a conflict, keep the first record and discard others. Since the list is already sorted, this step will ensure that the first record for an `id` will be kept while others will be discarded. Check [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) to learn more about this.
3. Collect the stream of values of the `Map` as the final `List`.

   ```
   List<NotificationCnavOP> result=
                   notificationCnavOPList
                   .stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(NotificationCnavOP::getId)
                           .thenComparing(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getDate(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")))
                           .thenComparing(NotificationCnavOP::getCxalap))
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(NotificationCnavOP::getId, Function.identity(), (e1, e2) -> e1))
                   .values()
                   .stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

### Demo:

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.function.Function;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            List<NotificationCnavOP> notificationCnavOPList = new ArrayList<>(
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new NotificationCnavOP(1, "01/01/2000", 1), 
                            new NotificationCnavOP(2, "01/01/2001", 2),
                            new NotificationCnavOP(2, "01/01/2002", 3), 
                            new NotificationCnavOP(2, "01/01/2001", 2)));

            List<NotificationCnavOP> result = 
                    notificationCnavOPList
                    .stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(NotificationCnavOP::getId)
                            .thenComparing(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getDate(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")))
                            .thenComparing(NotificationCnavOP::getCxalap))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(NotificationCnavOP::getId, Function.identity(), (e1, e2) -> e1))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }

    class NotificationCnavOP {
        private int id;
        private String date;
        private int cxalap;

        public NotificationCnavOP(int id, String date, int cxalap) {
            this.id = id;
            this.date = date;
            this.cxalap = cxalap;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public int getCxalap() {
            return cxalap;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + id + ", " + date + ", " + cxalap + "]";
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
    [[1, 01/01/2000, 1], [2, 01/01/2001, 2]]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rFAR6H)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much ! But I have a "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException"  with the line :
 .thenComparing(e -> LocalDate.parse(e.getDate(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")). Do you know why ?

Comment: @Pelodido3 - Did you copy and run my code as it is?

Comment: By copying your code entirely, I have an incompatible types :
 "Date cannot be converted to CharSequence"
So I tried to add a .toString() and I had have this error : 
"java.time.format.DateTimeParseException"

Comment: @Pelodido3 - It seems you've missed something which I'm not able to guess. The code I have posted is tested. I just tested it again and there is no compilation or runtime error.

Comment: @Pelodido3 - You might have imported some wrong class(es). I've updated my code with the `import` statements as well. I hope, it helps.